# Generating Primary Key Syntax in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, primary-key

I am currently designing a rich web app with psql. In order to keep track of entries, I want to have sets of primary keys in the format x-yyyy, where x is a char dependent on the type of entity, and y is a random alphanumeric character. These will ultimately act as master keys for all further information stored for each entry.

How do I create a primary key field in a table with these constraints? Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: You will need to create a trigger that does this. There is no built-in functionality (the `yyyy` could be retrieved from a sequence though)

Comment: Please don't make that the actual `PRIMARY KEY`. A secondary `UNIQUE` index, if you must, but it's *strongly* preferable to have this kind of thing in separate fields. 

In this case, I strongly suggest a composite key: `PRIMARY KEY(x, yyyy)`.

Comment: If there's any correlation between x and yyyy you'll also eventually run into performance issues (because the planner assumes column independence and will simply multiply row count percentage estimates together, which is incorrect for correlated columns). I've had some luck with partial indexes on yyyy where x = each type identifier or partitioning if/when the data gets that large (especially when one type begins to dominate the others in terms of volume).